# How to import local global types with unplugin-auto-import？

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vite

In my project I hope I can import types from `/src/typings` globally with `unplugin-auto-import/vite`.

Code in my `/src/typings/index.ts`

```
export type AccountListSearchInfo = {
  page_size: number 
}
```

Settings for `unplugin-auto-import/vite`

```
AutoImport({
  dts: true,
  imports: [
     ...,
    {
      from: '@/typings',
      imports: ['AccountListSearchInfo'],
      type: true,
    }
  ]
})
```

The `auto-imports.d.ts` file shows

```
declare global {
  // @ts-ignore
  export type { Component, ComponentPublicInstance, ComputedRef, InjectionKey, PropType, Ref, VNode } from 'vue'
  // @ts-ignore
  export type { RouteLocationRaw, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
  // @ts-ignore
  export type { AccountListSearchInfo } from '@/typings'
}
```

But actually `export type { AccountListSearchInfo } from '@/typings'` does not work.
Types in `@/typings` are not imported yet.

How to import local global types with unplugin-auto-import？

Answer (score 0):

To import types globally in a project using unplugin-auto-import with Vite, I think you should update the imports from `'@/typing'` to `'src/typing'`

```js
AutoImport({
  dts: true,
  imports: [
     ...,
    {
      from: 'src/typings',
      imports: ['AccountListSearchInfo'],
      type: true,
    }
  ]
})
```

I tested it on my config and it works.

my config:

```js
AutoImport({
      imports: [
        'vue',
        '@vueuse/core',
        'pinia',
        {
          axios: [['default', 'axios']]
        },
        {
          from: 'src/types',
          type: true,
          imports: ['IUser']
        }
      ],
      dirs: ['src/composables'],
      dts: true,
      vueTemplate: true,
      eslintrc: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }),
```

using `unplugin-auto-import: "^0.17.3"`